# I can't implement vue-social-sharing

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to use vue-social-sharing but I get this error
[nuxt] error caught during app initialization TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '$SocialSharing')

## my plugins/socialSharing.ts

`import VueSocialSharing from "vue-social-sharing";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({vueApp}) => {
vueApp.use(VueSocialSharing)`your text`
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the Vue 3 module
`npm install --save vue-social-sharing@next`

`~/plugins/social-sharing.ts`

```js
import VueSocialSharing from 'vue-social-sharing'
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueSocialSharing)
})
```

Component usage example.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <ClientOnly>
            <ShareNetwork
                network="twitter"
                url="http://localhost:3000"
                title="Say hi to Vite! A brand new, extremely fast development setup for Vue."
                description="This week, I’d like to introduce you to 'Vite', which means 'Fast'. It’s a brand new development setup created by Evan You."
                quote="The hot reload is so fast it\'s near instant. - Evan You"
                hashtags="vuejs,vite,javascript"
                twitterUser="youyuxi"
            >
                <i class="fab fah fa-lg fa-twitter"></i>
                <span>Share on Twitter</span>
            </ShareNetwork>
        </ClientOnly>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]